# Orion Context Broker and CKAN professional hosting service?

Tags: fiware, ckan, fiware-orion

Is there any Orion Context Broker and CKAN professional hosting service? How can I get them on cloud and access with a good scalability as I'm going to use these applications in my real project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- Host those components in a mainstream cloud platform, AWS, Azure, etc.
- Use a FIWARE Cloud platform. You can find existing providers at

http://marketplace.fiware.org/pages/platforms